# Compile and run a 32bit binary on Armv8 (aarch64) running 64bit linux

Tags: gcc, compilation, 32bit-64bit, armv8

I'am trying to compile and run a 32 bit binary on a Cortex-A72 Armv8 using gcc compiler but i am not able to do it. I followed this prior thread [Having trouble compiling 32-bit binary on 64-bit linux armv8 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976837/having-trouble-compiling-32-bit-binary-on-64-bit-linux-armv8-machine#44977058) and i am realized too that the -m32 flag is not supported on ARMv8 linux machines.
Looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html i didn’t find anything interesting.

In according to https://linux.die.net/man/1/arm-linux-gnu-gcc the AArch64 gcc options are:

```
-mbig-endian -mlittle-endian -mgeneral-regs-only -mcmodel=tiny -mcmodel=small -mcmodel=large -mstrict-align -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -mtls-dialect=desc -mtls-dialect=traditional -march=name -mcpu=name -mtune=name
```

So my question is: is it possible to compile and run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit linux Armv8 machine ? and is so, how ?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** this https://jensd.be/1126/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-or-aarch64-on-debian-or-ubuntu worked for me

Comment: Use a version of GCC that targets Aarch32 instead of the default one for your host machine.

Comment: @Michael Any suggestion ? i am using the  10.2.1 version

Comment: Either find an existing package for your Linux distro, or build GCC yourself from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the *AArch32 target with hard float (arm-none-linux-gnueabihf)* toolchain from the [Cortex-A toolchain Arm site](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

The archive file name is [gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.2-2020.11/binrel/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz?revision=26cbedef-a2fa-4687-b6bb-2fefc0d3c5d6&la=en&hash=9137A71DC9572E22A40BE62B1BF0C5800EB52E6A), in the *AArch64 Linux hosted cross compilers* section.

You may need to install additional packages on your Aarch64 system - search for *How to run 32-bit (armhf) binaries on 64-bit (arm64)* and your Linux distribution name.